# TinyMCE return html tags

Tags: javascript, php, html, encoding, tinymce

Hi I got a problem with TinyMCE and can't find solution, I know there is some post related but doesn't work for me...

Exemple :

- On my back office, when i wrote something like that : 
  [image: When writting]
- On form submit, post data look like that : 
  [image: saving]
- After save, i'll be redirected to the page and get that
  [image: after redirect]

I dont understand what happen ...

Here is my init :

```
    tinyMCE.init({
        mode : "specific_textareas",
        editor_deselector : /(minimce|nomce)/,
        toolbar: "undo redo | styleselect | bold italic underline | forecolor | link unlink | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist",
        autosave_ask_before_unload: false,
        toolbar_items_size: 'small',
        height:150,
        plugins: [
            "advlist autolink lists link image charmap",
            "code textcolor",
        ],
    });
```

I get same result with an empty init. 
Someone can explain me what happen ?

Thanks you !

Comment: What version of TinyMCE are you using?

Comment: i see the pics but i don't see the problem.

Comment: maybe you missing some http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration3x:mode ~ Converts all textarea elements to editors when the page loads.

Comment: Thanks for your help ! 

@DanielB I use TinyMCE 4.1.9 
And Dagon the problem is that there is no more WYSYWYG after save, all the content is output in html. 
And nope don't change anything ... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rhaaaaaaaaaa ! I simply used a form helper from Codeigniter : form_textarea();
Which look like to not work with tinyMCE ... I dont know why, probably some encoding reason.

**Simply replacing with a classic `<textarea>` work just fine.**

Thanks for your help anyway !

Answer (score 0):

Strange, I was breaking my brains on this for a couple of hours and came to the same conclusion.
form_textarea is breaking tinymce
but using  is working fine..

Thanks for the help